# Как передать событие event в обработчик событий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется обработчик события:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#saveInfo', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this.form);
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
    })
});
```

Хочу добавить еще обработчик делающий схожий функционал, и соответственно, нужно вынести обработчик из анонимной функции в один общий обработчик. Никак не пойму как сделать handler, который будет передавать текущий event события.
По идее должно получится что-то по типу этого:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#saveInfo', (e) => sendInfo(e));

const sendInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this.form);
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
    })
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `const sendInfo = (e) => {` на `const sendInfo = function(e) {`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вызов `sendInfo(e)` портит контекст.

Comment: @Igor и объявление `sendInfo` тоже портит контекст...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#container').on('click', '#saveInfo', sendInfo);

function sendInfo(e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все оказалось проще чем я думал)